# Linearing programming with Pulp: Error with LpAffineExpression

Tags: python, typeerror, linear-programming

I'm currently using the pulp package to work on linear programming.
I tried to set the dependent variable which varies with the decision variable but failed... 
What I did was:

```
opt = LpProblem(name="OPT")

# Data
df={"A":[5,4,3,4,6]}
a=df["A"]

# Set decision variable 
var=LpVariable.dicts("Var", df.index, lowBound=-3.3, upBound=3.3, cat="Continuous")

# Set dependent variable
k={}
for i in df.index:
    k[i]=math.tanh(-var[i])

# Set constraints
opt += a[i]-var[i] >= 0

# Define the objective function
opt += lpSum ((a[i]-var[i])*k[i]) for i in df.index)

opt_model.solve()
```

And I got "TypeError: must be real number, not LpAffineExpression". 
I am wondering how can I set the decision variable in the tanh function.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There are two related errors here.

1. `math.tanh` does not know about decision variables. It can only take numbers as an argument.
2. Even if it was allowed, this is still non-sensical as this would make the problem non-linear. PuLP is only for linear models.